# How to separate different size of multiple-character values inside row?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this dummy input dataframe which contains character values with different sizes for each variable. (Input dataframe cannot be changed)

```
data <- data.frame(c('c(a1, a10)'),
                   c('c(b1)'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(data) <- c('A', 'B')
head(data)
#          A     B
#1 c(a1, a10) c(b1)
```

And I would like to turn this dataframe to below dataframe. Tidyverse, dplyr approach will be helpful.

```
#    A            B
#1  a1           b1
#2 a10           NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with splitting the data on comma (`,`) and appending `NA`'s for data with shorter lengths in each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~strsplit(gsub('c\\(|\\)', '', .), ',\\s*'))) %>%
  pmap_df(~{
    x <- list(...)
    max_len <- 1:max(lengths(x))
    lapply(x, `[`, max_len)
  })

#   A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a1    b1   
#2 a10   NA
```

Testing on another dataset.

```
data <- data.frame(A = c('c(a1, a10, a11)', 'c(a1)'), 
                   B = c('c(b1, b10)', 'c(b1, b2)'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


data %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~strsplit(gsub('c\\(|\\)', '', .), ',\\s*'))) %>%
  pmap_df(~{
    x <- list(...)
    max_len <- 1:max(lengths(x))
    lapply(x, `[`, max_len)
  })

#   A     B    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a1    b1   
#2 a10   b10  
#3 a11   NA   
#4 a1    b1   
#5 NA    b2
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Assuming your data is actually like: df1 => data.frame
df1 <- setNames(
   data.frame(
      cbind(A = list(c('a1', 'a10')), B = list('b1')),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
   ),
   c('A', 'B')
)

# Unlist each column: ir => list of character vectors
ir <- lapply(
   df1, 
   unlist, 
   recursive = FALSE
)

# Extend out each list to be the same length as the largest list,
# column bind each list into a data.frame: res => data.frame
res <- data.frame(
   do.call(
      cbind, 
      lapply(
         ir, 
         function(x){
            length(x) <- max(lengths(ir)); x
         }
      )
   ),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
   row.names = NULL
)

# Output result: data.frame => stdout(console)
res

# Otherwise if your data is actually like this: df2 => data.frame
df2 <- data.frame(
   A = c('c(a1, a10)'), 
   B = c('c(b1)'),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Split the strings out into separater elements store as list:
# ir => list of character vectors
ir <- lapply(
   df2,
   function(x){
      trimws(
         gsub(
            "^c\\(|\\)$",
            "",
            unlist(
               strsplit(
                  x,
                  ","
                  )
               )
            )
      )
   }
)

# Extend out each list to be the same length as the largest list,
# column bind each list into a data.frame: res2 => data.frame
res2 <- data.frame(
   do.call(
      cbind, 
      lapply(
         ir, 
         function(x){
            length(x) <- max(lengths(ir)); x
         }
      )
   ),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
   row.names = NULL
)

# Output result: data.frame => stdout(console)
res2
```